# Calculating average in python using while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, average

Alright, I'm stumped on creating a function in python that uses a while loop to calculate an average. Using a for loop is simple, but I don't get how to recreate this function using a while loop instead.

```
def average(list):
    total = 0.0
    for number in list:
        total = total + number
    return total / len(list)
```

Could anyone give me a hand in how to use a while loop for this function?

Comment: You should tag homework as such.

Comment: Please do not *ever* use `list` as a variable name. You're shadowing the built-in type `list`.

Comment: And why use a while loop? Is it a homework? The good way is : `avg = float(sum(l))/len(l)`

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- You can get values out of a list using indexing, `s[i]` for example.
- The while-loop needs to test to see when you've reached the end of a list.
- You can tell when you're at the end of a list by using *len()*

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a helpful hint. In python lists you can access the element in a list using square brackets like so: `list[3]`. This will return the **4th** element in the list. The first element is at index 0 (`list[0]`).

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 0
total = 0.0
while(i < len(list))
    total = total + list[i]
    i = i+1
return total/len(list)
```

But why do you want to use `for` and `while` for this task in the first place? It is easier to use a functional approach, like

```
return reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, list) / len(list)
```

or just

```
return sum(list) / len(list)
```

Comment: Your functional approaches have a bug.